nodemon does not work with hot reloading in docker
I'm trying to make hot reloading in docker with an express server using nodemon to monitor the js files. The problem is that when I change something in local, it changes in the docker container but the server is not restarted(I used cat to check the file changed in the docker terminal). When I add or remove file using touch command in the docker terminal, the server restart.
The docker file:
` docker
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
`
build command :
docker build -t myapp .
run command :
 docker run --name myapp -d -v ${pwd}:/app  -p 3000:3000 myapp
I expect when I change a file in the local, the server restarts in the docker container.
I tried to use node --watch
